# BLPOP blocks my redis connection when using it in multiple running queues

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

I have 8 queues running and I want to pop if the queue has a push. The application has multiple users and the queues are almost always having data.

I want to replace `LPOP` with `BLPOP` but using it in all the queues doesn't pop the data

here is a sample of my code

```
async function queuePop(queue) {
    const value = await redis.blpop(queue, 0);
    if (value) {
        const data = JSON.parse(value[1]);
        return data;
    }
}

async function processQueue(queue) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            const data = await popFromQueue(queue);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error processing job', err);
        }
    }
}

function ProcessingFunction(data) {
    const data = await processQueue('queueName')
    console.log(`Processing data: ${data}`);
}

calling ProcessingFunction() in a setTimeout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement BLPOP for multiple queues, we need multiple instances of Redis Client.
For example:

```
const queues = { name: 'queue1', client: null, ... }
// assigning the instance of the Redis client to all the queues in the queues
```

and Thus when there is no data in the queue1, the connection will drop for that instance and the same goes for all instances of Redis client.

There is a limitation for `BLPOP` as one cannot use Limit like we do in `LPOP`